# Is such set a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Question:** If a set $G$ is equipped with an associative binary operation $\ast$, and assume $G$ has identity element $e$ and for each $g \in G$ there exists its inverse element $g^{-1}$, is $G$ a group?

Here is the original question and solution:
[image]

I have done pretty much the same job as above, but like the solution, there is no check on closure of the operation $\ast$. Actually I don't think we can do that because for example $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ as a subset of $\Bbb Z$ with the same operation of $+$ in $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is not closed under it.

I am so frustrated and could someone please explain?

Comment: Your question in yellow does not match the original question.

Comment: having a binary operation on a set means the set is closed under the operation. That is the meaning of being a binary operation on a set.

Comment: Indeed, the question in yellow has an obvious affirmative answer because this is the definition of a group. Closure is implicit; otherwise there is no such binary operation.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss Oh it seems I misunderstood the concept. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just want to make a small note about the way you phrased a portion of your question (I know I'm nitpicking).  You said there exists an inverse for all $g$.  Because of the way you ordered the quantifiers ($\exists g^{-1} \forall g$), you are saying there is a single element that acts as the inverse for every element in the group.  Actually, different elements can have different inverses, so the correct way to phrase the statement is: for each element, there exists an inverse (i.e., $\forall g, \exists g^{-1}$).

Comment: The definition of a group can be made with somewhat different levels of generality. Most books assume the 2 sided nature of a unique identity and  the unique inverse of every element-but this definition can be given with the weaker axioms of a left or a right identity and for every element, there is at least one left inverse. It turns out these definitions are equivalent-the weaker axioms require proving both 2 sidedness and uniqueness for a left identity and each left inverse-you can also begin with right identities and inverses.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Your first part of the formulation makes it sound like right identity and left inverse would be enough (which it is not). Given the last sentence, I don't think this was intended.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a binary operation is a map from $G\times G \to G$ so it is closed. If in addition to that set also has an identity for that operation, and every element has an inverse, then you've got a group my friend.